# How to visualize the data of "5-Megapixel camera" and "LED Texture Projector Triggered with Narrow-Angle Stereo Camera" in rviz?

Tags: rviz, pr2, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to use rviz to confirm the functions of "5-Megapixel camera" and "LED Texture Projector Triggered with Narrow-Angle Stereo Camera" works well,

but I cannot find the correct topic to visualize the camera data, does anyone know how to view in rviz?

EDIT:
I found [a page](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter9#Head_Cameras) that may be useful for this question.
Now my understanding is, projector illuminates the objects. To visualize the data of "LED Texture Projector Triggered with Narrow-Angle Stereo Camera", I should start the projector first, then I can view narrow_stereo_textured data on rviz. Is this correct?

Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48898/how-to-visualize-the-data-of-%225-megapixel-camera%22-and-%22led-texture-projector-triggered-with-narrow-angle-stereo-camera%22-in-rviz?/) by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1371 on 2012-11-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the answer based on this [page](http://pr2support.willowgarage.com/wiki/PR2%20Manual/Chapter9#Head_Cameras).

1.To check whether "5-Megapixel camera" works well on PR2. Just use dashboad, select the "camera" and choose "Prosilica".
To work with this camera, the tutorials is stated [here](http://ros.org/wiki/prosilica_camera/Tutorials).

2.And for "LED Texture Projector Triggered with Narrow-Angle Stereo Camera". To start projector, reference this [page](http://ros.org/wiki/dynamic_reconfigure).
Use this

```
rosrun dynamic_reconfigure reconfigure_gui
select /camera_synchronizer_node
turn the "projector mode" to "ProjectorOn"
```

Then you can see the projector shining.To use this projector, see this [page](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_camera_synchronizer).

---

Originally posted by [Po-Jen Lai](https://answers.ros.org/users/1352/po-jen-lai/) with karma: 1371 on 2012-12-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0